How to get tx signature(s) when using send_and_confirm_transactions_in_parallel()
I am using tpu_client to send tx with fn send_and_confirm_transactions_in_parallel(), basically it worked smoothly, but I don't know where to get the tx signature(s). Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot. Below is my source code:
    let connection_cache = ConnectionCache::new_quic("connection_cache_my_quic", 1);

    let transaction_errors = match connection_cache {
        ConnectionCache::Quic(cache) => {
            let tpu_client = TpuClient::new_with_connection_cache(
                rpc_client.clone(),
                websocket_url.clone().as_str(),
                TpuClientConfig::default(),
                cache,
            )
            .await?;
            send_and_confirm_transactions_in_parallel(
                rpc_client.clone(),
                Some(tpu_client),
                messages,
                &[signer],
                config,
            )
            .await
        },

        _ => return Err(format!("unsupported connection cache").into()),
    }
    .map_err(|err| format!("Data writes to account failed: {err}"))?
    .into_iter()
    .flatten()
    .collect::<Vec<_>>();


Since the function takes in the base Messages and the signers required for them, it doesn't output all of the signatures. You can certainly hack this in though!
The source code exists at https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/master/client/src/send_and_confirm_transactions_in_parallel.rs, and you might want to log the signatures at few points:

they are signed at https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/10bebfaf422b8e09409cc5b56a35ec40defa27aa/client/src/send_and_confirm_transactions_in_parallel.rs#L269
they are confirmed at https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/10bebfaf422b8e09409cc5b56a35ec40defa27aa/client/src/send_and_confirm_transactions_in_parallel.rs#L134

Since transactions may be resigned multiple times, if you want to know the transactions that actually landed, you'll want to log the signatures at the second point.
